# A GRE subject problem about linear algebra [duplicated]

Tags: linear-algebra, gre-exam

The problem is:

> Let $V$ be the real vector space of all real $2×3$ matrices and let
>   $W$ be the real vector space of all real $4×1$ column vectors. If T is
>   a linear transformation from $V$ onto $W$. What is the dimension of
>   the subspace $\{v\in V:T(v)=0\}$?

I see this problem in GRE practice book. I search this problem in Mathematics exchange and there is an [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221836/some-gre-questions-ii).

@André Nicolas gives an answer that since $\dim(V)=6$ and $\dim(W)=4$, then $\ker(T)=6-4=2$. I am confused that why $\ker(T)=\dim(V)-\dim(W)$? I just know the Rank plus nullity theorem that $nullity(T)+rank(T)=\dim(T)$. So how his formula is true? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The rank is the dimension of the range.  Since your transformation is onto, the rank is the same as the dimension of $W$.  Also, the nullity is the dimension of the kernel.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 OK, now I get it. Thank you for your answer!

Comment: Oh.  I didn't see that.  It should be $\dim(V)$, not $\dim(T)$.  Linear transformations don't have dimensions.

Comment: @JoeJohnson126 OK, thank you again. By the way, I also confuse that what is the definition of dimension of matrix (or vector)? Is that the number of components included by matrix or the rank of the matrix?

Comment: Yes.  So an $n\times m$ matrix is of dimension $nm$.  An $n\times 1$ column vector has dimension $n$.

Answer (score 1):

The key is that the linear transformation is "onto" $W$.  So the dimension of the image is the dimension of $W$, namely 4.  Thus by the rank-nullity theorem, dim(kernel) + dim(image) = dim(domain), we get dim(kernel) + 4 = 6.  So the dimension of the kernel is 2.  Of course the kernel is precisely the subspace $\{v\in V : T(v) = \vec{0}\}$.

Comment: OK, now I get it, thank you for your answer!